# Woocommerce existing product content not updating/changing after hitting update button in edit product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to update a simple product description and sale price from the product edit page in the WordPress admin panel. After making changes when I hit the update button it shows the product updated but again description and sale price of that product reverted back to the previous one.

Seems like content is not updating in the wp_postmeta table, When I tried to view that product wp_post it was showing the old modification date.

I repaired both table wp_postmeta and wp_post using the PHPMyAdmin panel, Still nothing.

I'm using the Genesis child theme. And not using any page builder like elementor etc for products.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Disable all plugins except woo and test. If still facing issue change theme to storefront. If still facing problems install Query Monitor and start debuging.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried to disable all plugins and also changed the theme but did not help. I will install Query Monitor now and will check.

Comment: Install fresh wordpress with woo and test. This could be bad update or something on yourside. I dont face any issues on test installations or live stores . Check your php setttings if some resources are limited or something.